# How can I preview a document to print in preview control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am developing a cheque printing app by my self. I want to preview the printed output in a `PrintPreviewControl`. The problem I am facing is I can't preview only the content I want to print. The `PrintPreviewControl` is showing the whole page in the document.

Below is a screenshot of a software and what I want my cheque print form to look like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnsave.Text = "Update";
            PrintDocument printcheque = new PrintDocument();
            printcheque.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printcheque_PrintPage);
            CreatePrintPreviewControl();
        }
        private void CreatePrintPreviewControl()
        {
            printPreviewControl1 = new PrintPreviewControl();
            printPreviewControl1.Name = "PrintPreviewControl1";
            printPreviewControl1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            printPreviewControl1.Location = new Point(24, 280);
            printPreviewControl1.Document = printcheque;
            printPreviewControl1.Zoom = 1.1;
            printPreviewControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(883, 247);
            // Add PrintPreviewControl to Form
            Controls.Add(this.printPreviewControl1);
        }
        private void printcheque_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            string numw;
            if (amnteng.Checked)
            {

                numw = NumberToWords(txtamount.Text);
                Font F = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
                Brush B = Brushes.Black;
                Pen P = new Pen(B, 1.0f);

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dateTimePicker1.Text, F, B, 180, 100); //date
                e.Graphics.DrawString(txtpaye.Text, F, B, 100, 110); //Payee
                e.Graphics.DrawString(numw, F, B, 330, 250);//Amount in Inwords
                e.Graphics.DrawString(txtamount.Text, F, B, 710, 150); //Amount
            }
            else
            {
                Font F = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
                Brush B = Brushes.Black;
                Pen P = new Pen(B, 1.0f);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dateTimePicker1.Text, F, B, 680, 100); //date
                e.Graphics.DrawString(txtpaye.Text, F, B, 100, 110); //Payee
                e.Graphics.DrawString(txtamount.Text, F, B, 710, 150); //Amount
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument printcheque = new PrintDocument();
            printcheque.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printcheque_PrintPage);
            PrintPreviewDialog xDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            xDialog.Document = printcheque;
            xDialog.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

I want preview to be like this:
[image: I want preview to be like this]

But it currently looks like this:
[image: My Form]

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Comment: @JohnM.Wright can you also help with the code please ?